# failbit not being set when seekg seeks past end of file (C++,Linux)

Tags: c++

I'm seeing what I think is odd behaviour of istream::seekg.  Specifically, it appears to
NOT set the failbit when I seek to a point that is clearly way off the end of the file.

From what I can tell in the documentation, the failbit should be set, yet it is not.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?  snippet of relevant code:

```
class Tester 
{

  ... 

  void testTriggered()
  {
    fs.open("/pathtofile/testFile.TEST", std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    prv_testbits("testTriggered(): OpeningFile");

    fs.seekg(2000,std::ios_base::beg);
    prv_testbits("testTriggered(): seekTwoThousand");
    int g = fs.tellg();
    std::cout << "get pointer is:" << g << std::endl; 
  }

  void prv_testbits(std::string msg){
    if (fs.fail()) {
      std::cout << msg << ": failbit set." << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << msg << ": failbit NOT set." << std::endl;
    }
    if (fs.bad()) {
      std::cout << msg << ": badbit set." << std::endl;
    }else {
      std::cout << msg << ": badbit NOT set." << std::endl;
    }
    if (fs.eof()) {
      std::cout << msg << ": eofbit set." << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << msg << ": eofbit NOT set." << std::endl;
    }
  }

   ....

 private:
  std::ifstream fs;
};
```

input file consists of twenty bytes:
    0123456789abcdefghij

output of sample run:

```
testTriggered(): OpeningFile: failbit NOT set.
testTriggered(): OpeningFile: badbit NOT set.
testTriggered(): OpeningFile: eofbit NOT set.
testTriggered(): seekTwoThousand: failbit NOT set.
testTriggered(): seekTwoThousand: badbit NOT set.
testTriggered(): seekTwoThousand: eofbit NOT set.
get pointer is:2000
```

g++ version info:
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5' -with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 [snip]
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

$ uname -a
Linux hostx 2.6.32-36-server #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 8 22:44:38 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Welcome to SO! You write, "*From what I can tell in the documentation …*" What documentation are you consulting, and what does it say?

Comment: Error flags in streams are typically set when an attempted read/write operation fails. The output "2000" indicates that the call to seekg() was successful - the get pointer is set, just not to a valid location.

Comment: Yes, you guessed it, I used cpluspplus.com as my documentation. I'm beginning to think that documentation might be erroneous, it indicates that the failbit should be set after seekg is called.  However, cppreference.com does not indicate this.

Comment: My reading of cplusplus.com's docs on this shows it saying that the `failbit` is set if "The parameter(s) describe a position that could not be reached". This doesn't contract the behavior you're seeing. Since seeking beyond the end of file is generally permitted - it just extends the size of the file if you subsequently write at that position - the position you specified (2000) could be reached.

Comment: One might argue that, since I have opened the file as readonly, that the 2000-th position might never be reached, unless someone else writes to the file :)  However, I think the bottom line is simply that seekg() does not set the failbit in this instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Open Group specification  for `fseek()` (likely used to implement `fstream::seekg`) is required to allow file positions beyond the current end-of-file:

> The *fseek()* function shall allow the file-position indicator to be set beyond the end of existing data in the file. If data is later written at this point, subsequent reads of data in the gap shall return bytes with the value 0 until data is actually written into the gap.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fseek.html

Comment: Yes, this is in keeping with how seekg is behaving.  Thanks for the feedback!