# Is this seemingly odd behaviour concerning seekp correct?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, stream, fstream

EDIT, apologies, this question is clearly a duplicate of [failbit not being set when seekg seeks past end of file (C++,Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022417/failbit-not-being-set-when-seekg-seeks-past-end-of-file-c-linux)

---

To get to where I'm at, firstly touch a file in the terminal to create an empty file (linux or mac):

```
touch test.file
```

And then compile and execute this code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream stream("test.file", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    stream.seekp(54765476543); // arbitrarily large number
    std::cout<<"stream.tellp() "<<stream.tellp()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"stream.bad()? "<<stream.bad()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"stream.fail()? "<<stream.fail()<<std::endl;
    stream << "test";
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

with your favourite c++ compiler (I tried Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) for clang++ and i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 for g++ and g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) on linux)

E.g.

```
clang++ testStream.cpp -o ts
```

When I run 'ts' I get the output:

```
stream.tellp() 54765476543
stream.bad()? 0
stream.fail()? 0
```

This is where my confusion arrises: I thought tellp() would give '-1' (since I'm trying to seek past the end) and that stream.fail() would at least equate to true. Is such behaviour undefined or am I missing something?

Even more curiously is that when I then do

```
ls -lh test.file
```

I get

```
-rw-r--r--  1 bjones  users    51G Aug 13 04:32 test.file
```

Now clearly the file isn't 54G in size. Finally when I do

```
cat test.file
```

to see if anything was actually written, the output just hangs.

Is the above behaviour correct?

Thanks,

Ben.

Comment: Its an output stream, seekp is going to create a file of size 54765476543 from your empty test.touch

Comment: That can't be true because a 'df' of the drive only shows a usage increase of 8 bytes (I could equally create a 10TB file by increasing the seek number, at least according to ls -h, which is far beyond the capacity of the drive)

Comment: You won't see a huge increase of your disk usage because it is most probably a *sparse* file, see [quantdev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25282704/1340631).

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that the file system could make such an optimization. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in doing a `seekp()` past the end of file (and possibly then write to it)

You really are writing this file by moving the cursor forward.

Whether the file *really* is that big (and if it is a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)) entirely depend on your OS/file system : as far as C++ is concerned, this is valid.